# java split does not work correctly with ^

Tags: java, split

I want to split a string for the character `^` but it does not work. I have the following code:

```
String numberBase10 = "3.52*10^2";
String[] vector = numberBase10.split("^"); 
System.out.println("numberBase10: " + numberBase10);
System.out.println("Vector[0]: " vector[0]);
```

I get the following output:

```
numberBase10: 3.52*10^2
Vector[0]: 3.52*10^2
```

And if I try to access vector[1] I get the error IndexOutOfArray.

I have to put any escape character so that split works with `^`?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape it with `\\^`.

^ is a special character by itself, meaning negation (in a group, such as [^abc], which matches anything but abc) or the anchor for beginning of line.

Answer (score 8):

`split` takes a regular expression. `^` is an anchor used to match the start of string in regex so needs to be escaped

```
String[] vector = numberBase10.split("\\^");
```

Answer (score 2):

The java string split method operates on a regex, and '^' is an anchor character in a regex so it must be escaped to treat it as a regular character:

```
String[] vector = numberBase10.split("\\^");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `^` is a special character as regular expression, you need to escape it - If I change to,

```
String[] vector = numberBase10.split("\\^");
```

Then I get

```
Vector[0]: 3.52*10
```

With no other code changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `split()` method expects a regular expression, if you want to split on an exact string without worrying about any regex special characters it may contain, you should escape it first with

`String regex = java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("^");`

Then split on `regex`. The whole concept can be packaged up in a nice static method:

```
public static String[] splitRaw(String input, String separator) {
    String regex = java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(separator);
    return input.split(regex);
}
```